# ¿Como posiciono un elemento en medio de una pantalla? HTML5 y CSS3

Tags: html, css

me encuentro aprendiendo HTML y CSS, se como organizar las cosas en el medio de la pantalla utilizando

```
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
```

pero no se como posicionar un bloque en medio de forma vertical.

El codigo CSS del bloque que quiero posicionar es el siguiente:

```css
.content {
  height: 350px;
  background-color: chocolate;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  padding: 5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Solamente verticalmente el centrado?

Comment: Claro, ya que horizontalmente lo que hago es margin-left:auto margin-right:auto @BetaM

Comment: que quieres posicionar o quieres posicionar todo lo que se encuentra dentro el contenerdor `.content`?. Por favor puedes agregar que tienes dentro de `.content`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con position o flexbox de css, te recomiendo este último, un ejemplo...
Tienes que meter tu contenedor en uno padre, y darle el alto que quieres dependiendo de a que altura quieres quieres centrarlo.

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh; /* suponiendo que quieres centrar respecto a todo el alto de la pantalla */
  width: 100%;
  display: flex; /* propiedad flexbox */
  justify-content: center; /* centra el contenido horizontalmmente */
  align-items: center; /* centra el contenido verticalmente */
}

.content{
  height: 350px;
  width: 350px;
  background-color: chocolate;
  padding: 5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: todavía no se sabe qué elemento quiere posicionar, ni que tecnología quiere usar flex, grid, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yo he usado este, lo importante en si es el margin, espero que te sirva

```css
.contenedor {
  width: 90%;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: rgba(66, 68, 63, 0.55);
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="contenedor">a</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ocupas una línea de CSS

```css
.content {
  text-align:center;
  height: 350px;/*Esta es la altura que le estás dando al div*/
  line-height:350px;/*Entonces le dices que el contenido se ajusto al centro de su propia altura*/
  background-color: chocolate;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  padding: 5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content"><h3>Aqui va el contenido</h3></div>
</div>
```

y eso es todo